# Apply scikit-learn model to pyspark dataframe column

Tags: pyspark, scikit-learn

I have a trained Scikit-learn LogisticRegression model in a sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline. This is an NLP task. The model is saved as a pkl file (actually in ML Studio models, but I download it to databricks dbfs).

I have a Hive table (delta-backed) containing some 1 million rows. The rows have, amongst other things, an *id*, a *keyword_context* column (containing the text), a *modelled* column (boolean, indicates the model has been run on this row), and a *prediction* column, which is an integer for the class output by the logistic regression.

My problem is how to update the prediction column.

running locally I can do

```
def generatePredictions(data:pd.DataFrame, model:Pipeline) -> pd.DataFrame:
  data.loc[:, 'keyword_context'] = data.keyword_context.apply(lambda x: x.replace("\n", " ")
  data['prediction'] = model.predict(data.keyword_context)
  data['modelled'] = True
  return data
```

This actually runs fast enough (~20s), but running the UPDATEs back to databricks via the databricks.sql.connector, takes many hours. So I want to do the same in a pyspark notebook to bypass the lengthy upload.

The trouble is that it is generally suggested to use inbuilt functions (which this isn't) or if there must be a udf then the examples all use inbuilt types, not Pipelines. I'm wondering whether the model should be loaded within the function, and I presume the function takes a single row, which means a lot of loading. I'm really not sure how to code the function, or call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on the [Fugue](https://github.com/fugue-project/fugue/) project which aims to provide a simpler interface than the Spark one for porting Python/Pandas code. This is actually the first use case in our tutorial. Fugue will use the underlying Spark call (pandas_udf, udf, mapPartitions, applyInPandas, mapInPandas) based on the arguments you provide with minimal overhead.

Here is what the code looks like.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

X = pd.DataFrame({"x_1": [1, 1, 2, 2], "x_2":[1, 2, 2, 3]})
y = np.dot(X, np.array([1, 2])) + 3
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)

def predict(df: pd.DataFrame, model: LinearRegression) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return df.assign(predicted=model.predict(df))

input_df = pd.DataFrame({"x_1": [3, 4, 6, 6], "x_2":[3, 3, 6, 6]})

sdf = spark.createDataFrame(input_df)

# This is the start of the Fugue portion. It's minimal
from fugue import transform

result = transform(
    sdf,
    predict,
    schema="*,predicted:double",
    params=dict(model=reg),
    engine=spark
)
print(type(result))
result.show()
```

This code will be applied per partition. Schema is a requirement for Spark. I am not sure but it sounds like you were using a row-wise UDF, so I think this will be faster. It also leaves your logic easy to unit test because you don't need Spark to unit test.

**On loading the file inside the function**

If you load the file inside the function, it gets executed on the workers. If you pass it in, it gets passed through the scheduler. This can create a lot of redundant passing of data. Loading it inside might speed things up.

Comment: I really like the look of Fugue, so thanks for that tip, I'll be using it in future. I haven't got it working for this case, yet. The spark DF is read from the delta lake, and calling 'show' after 'transform' gives 'Value Error: Length of values (3) does not match length of index(119849). But I'll work on it. Going through the docs now to understand better.

Comment: You can reach out to me and I can take a closer look at your code. My contact info is in my profile (and on my Github)

Comment: Just to follow up, this is now working very well. In Databricks, having loaded the pickled Scikit-learn- NLP pipeline, I have: `def predict(df:pd.DataFrame, model:Pipeline) -> pd.DataFrame:
  df.loc[:, 'keyword_context'] = df.keyword_context.apply(lambda x: x.replace("\n", " "))
  df['model_policy'] = model.predict(df.keyword_context)
  df['modelled'] = True
  return df`
`from fugue import transform

result = transform(
  captures_table,
  predict,
  schema="*+model_policy:int8",
  params=dict(model=model),
  engine=spark
)`
Fugue solves the problem nicely. Thanks!